# Apache Spark Join operation across multiple nodes

Tags: apache-spark, join, nodes, operation

I am using Spark2.1 version and i have a basic question on how the spark join works internally.

Assume there are 2 set of pair RDD's as shown below in distributed across 2 data nodes:

**Employee RDD(Employee ID and Dept): Node 1:**
(100,ADAM)
(101,JOHN)
(102,TERRY)

**Dependent RDD (Employee ID and No. of Dependents): Node 1**
(100,3)
(101,2)
(202,3)

**Employee RDD(Employee ID and Dept): Node 2:**
(200,TOM)
(201,VIC)
(202,MARIA)

**Dependent RDD (Employee ID and No. of Dependents): Node 2**
(102,5)
(200,1)
(201,4)

Based on the above data distribution, if the join is happening on the above 2 Pair RDD's, then how join operation will happen on the data locality, because
in Node 1, Spark will not be able to find the matching key for 102 in Node 1.

But the value for this join is available in Node 2. So will spark load data from all the nodes to complete the join operation? Wont it be a bottleneck if that happens?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe in the question is called a shuffle operation in Spark , you are correct saying it creates a bottleneck and It is recommended to keep the shuffle operations to a minimum. it createsa bottleneck but its unavoidable.

Relevant resource for shuffle operations:
https://0x0fff.com/spark-architecture-shuffle/

Examples for shuffle operations : reduce,join